# Can I both record video and streaming live video at the same time?

Tags: android, video, video-streaming

It might be a similar question with this :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16453858/android-stream-and-record-at-the-same-time

I've tried to make a live video streaming on Android, and using spydroid library, it works really well.

- spydroid project : https://code.google.com/p/spydroid-ipcamera/

But the problem is I need to both live video streaming and video recording to the sd card at the same time. However, in the code, `setOutputFile()` specify socket's file descriptor :

```
        createSockets();
        // We write the ouput of the camera in a local socket instead of a file !           
        // This one little trick makes streaming feasible quiet simply: data from the camera
        // can then be manipulated at the other end of the socket
        mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(mSender.getFileDescriptor());
```

In here, `mSender` is `LocalSocket` object.

But like you guys already know, to record video to sd card in Android, we should specify file path to the `setOutputFile()` method. But we can't do both of them.

If I record live video in client side, then I can do it, but I want to do it on server side.

Do you have any thought or idea? Small hint can be very helpful to me. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: have you got solution of it? I am also trapped in same problem seriously. Thanks.